# nuget package problems with content hub linq queries

Tags: content-hub

I am trying to create a very basic test project to see if I can query content hub using linq [as the documentation suggests](https://docs.stylelabs.com/contenthub/4.0.x/content/integrations/sdk-common-documentation/query/query-linq.html?rp=true) and am having some trouble.

I have created a .net5 console application and added the StyleLabs.M.Sdk.WebClient 4.1.1 nuget package from a nuget source configured for https://slpartners.myget.org/f/m-public/api/v3/index.json.

For my first attempt, visual studio complains:

> 'Query' does not contain a definition for 'Take'...

I tried adding the StyleLabs.M.Querying.Linq nuget package, but when I attempt to add the package, package manager complains:

> Unable to find package Sitecore.Quince.Utilities. No packages exist with this id in source(s) (...)

Next I tried adding StyleLabs.M.Base.Querying 3.3.26. This restored successfully, and `Take` was now accepted as an extension to `Query`. But instead, `Query` became the problem!

> The type `Query` exists in both StyleLabs.M.Base.Querying and StyleLabs.M.Sdk

I'm tearing my hair out here. I already do have a project that uses the non-linq query methods, but I am attempting to follow the documentation's recommendation.

If I remove the *WebClient* namespaces I no longer get a conflict, but if I remove those namespaces then I don't have a client.. so... shrug!

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Q = Stylelabs.M.Base.Querying;
using Stylelabs.M.Base.Querying.Linq; // visual studio indicates this is not being used
using WCA = Stylelabs.M.Sdk.WebClient.Authentication;
using WC = Stylelabs.M.Sdk.WebClient;

internal class Program
{
    private static void  Main(string[] args)
    {
        var grant = new WCA.OAuthPasswordGrant { /**/ };
        var client = WC.MClientFactory.CreateMClient(new Uri(""), grant);
        var query = Q.Query.CreateQuery(entities =>
           from e in entities
           select e).Take(10); 

    }
}
```

With only the StyleLabs.M.Sdk.WebClient 4.1.1 package added, I get

> 'Query' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'Query' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

With the StyleLabs.M.Sdk.WebApiClient 3.1.4 *also* added, I get

> The type 'Query' exists in both 'Stylelabs.M.Base.Querying, Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Stylelabs.M.Sdk, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
> Blockquote

Help? Ideally, what I'd like is a list of the very first few steps to follow once I have, say, a bare console application created. Like:

1. Add the *insert specific package name and version here* nuget package.
2. Add the *insert another specific name and version here* nuget package
3. ...
4. Add `using ...`
5. call `MClientFactory.CreateMClient(..)`
6. Create the query object using `Query.CreateQuery(...)`

Comment: Without seeing all your `using` statements, its hard to know the actual problem. But my guess is that one of your `using` namespaces is giving you the wrong `Query` static object or you don't have the required `using` statement that contains the `CreateQuery` extension method.

Comment: @RichardSeal Cheers. The original usings are as per the linked doc, I have added them to the question. I think I have an idea of what's going on here... this seems to be related to the usage of `IWebMClient` vs `IMClient`. My existing (non linq) solution uses `IWebMClient`. There may also be issues created by package versioning... I have the latest stable for all of the packages, but if I downgrade webclient to 3.. I get different behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Query object, it only has a Take property available. It's not an IQuerable that you create with Query.CreateQuery. Therefore you can't use LINQ method TAKE, to set the property.

That said, you could of course always use extension methods for this purpose.

```
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static Query Take(this Query query, int take)
    {
        query.Take = take;

        return query;
    }
}
```